# Determine if url is a pdf or html file

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am requesting urls using the requests package in python (e.g. file = requests.get(url)).  The urls do not specify an extension in them, and sometimes a html file is returned and sometimes a pdf is returned.

Is there a way of determining if the returned file is a pdf or a html, or more generally, what the file format is? The browser is able to determine, so I assume it must be indicated in the response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will be found in the `Content-Type` header, either `text/html` or `application/pdf`

```
 import requests

 r = requests.get('http://example.com/file')
 content_type = r.headers.get('content-type')

 if 'application/pdf' in content_type:
     ext = '.pdf'
 elif 'text/html' in content_type:
     ext = '.html'
 else:
     ext = ''
     print('Unknown type: {}'.format(content_type))

 with open('myfile'+ext, 'wb') as f:
     f.write(r.raw.read())
```