# Determine if url is a pdf or html file in R

Tags: r

Like the person who asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690586/determine-if-url-is-a-pdf-or-html-file) question, I am keen to know how I can identify whether a URL is pointing towards an HTML file or PDF.

I am however looking for a solution using R - preferably avoiding the need to run Python through R, (eg. using reticulate, and the solution linked above)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option which might work here would be to use `curlGetHeaders` which is part of base R.  It returns a character vector containing all headers for a given input URL.  You may first grep that response for `Content-Type`, and then check the content type.

```
url <- "http://www.google.com"
headers <- curlGetHeaders(url)
ct <- headers[grep("Content-Type", headers, ignore.case=TRUE)]
# then check the content type for PDF or HTML
```

Answer (score 3):

```
install.packages("httr")
library(httr)
r <- GET("http://www.owsiak.org")
my_content_type <- headers(r)['content-type']
if(startsWith(my_content_type[[1]], 'text/html')) {
  print("HTML")
} else if(startsWith(my_content_type[[1]], "image/png")) {
  print("IMAGE")
}

r <- GET("http://www.owsiak.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/furie.png")
my_content_type <- headers(r)['content-type']
if(startsWith(my_content_type[[1]], 'text/html')) {
  print("HTML")
} else if(startsWith(my_content_type[[1]], "image/png")) {
  print("IMAGE")
}
```